# Name-Based Port Redirect

Tags: linux, redhat, port-forwarding

## Desired Effect

- **request** *server1.foobar.com:25565* **result** *server1.foobar.com:25565*
- **request** *server2.foobar.com:25565* **result** *server1.foobar.com:25566*
- **request** *server3.foobar.com:25565* **result** *server1.foobar.com:25567*
- **request** *server4.foobar.com:25565* **result** *server1.foobar.com:25568*

## Explanation

I am setting up a gaming server and I would like to run multiple servers from the same box but have them all use the same default port so that the user only has to enter the url of there desired server server1.foobar.com, server2.foobar.com, etc...

## Current Setup

- Basic Redhat server
- Webmin
- Apache
- MySQL
- SSH Access

Comment: What do you expect? A step by step video that someone records for you, a pointer to a personal free trainer that reads the documentation of webmin for you, or someone to log into your server and do everything, possibly even paying his bill? What have you tried?

Comment: TomTom: I expect the benefit of the doubt. I would not have asked the question here if I had not searched both on google and here before hand. I feel that your insinuation that I did not and want someone to do it for me very insulting. I do not expect nor even want any of that what I wanted is to know if it was even possible and if so what software can do it and hopefully what it is called so I can look it up in the documentation. The reason I included the "Current Setup" is to make the people reading the question more informed about where I am currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If *server[1-4].foobar.com* all resolve to the same IP address and you do not have a protocol which would transport the requested host name (basically no protocol aside from HTTP does so, especially the [Minecraft protocol](http://mc.kev009.com/Protocol) you apparently are intending to use does not) along with a proxy which would be able to rewrite and forward your requests accordingly, it won't work out.

If you *do* have different IP addresses for those names, then again you really should not forward anything but just let your daemons bind to the according addresses with the default port number. Forwarding only would unnecessarily complicate your setup without any benefit for your use case.